# Values in array are not accessible outside fetch codeblock

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, fetch-api

If I try to console.log the array 'profiles' I only get results when in the fetch code block, outside fetch code block the array is empty. Anyone has an idea how this comes?

I removed some variables to reduce the code but the problem only takes place outside of the fetch code block, in other words, outside of the function `getTinderProfiles()`.

While I'm clearly storing the data of the person object in the array 'profiles' I can not think of a problem to log the data of that array.

```
let url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=11';
let profiles = [];
let Person = new Object();

function getTinderProfiles() {
  fetch(url)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (tinderUsers) {

  // Get 10 users and put data in object
  let randomUser = tinderUsers.results;
  for (let i = 0; i < randomUser.length; i++) {
    Person = {
      picture: randomUser[i].picture.large,
      name: randomUser[i].name.first + ' ' + randomUser[i].name.last,
      age: 'Age: ' + randomUser[i].dob.age,
      location: randomUser[i].location.city + ' ' + randomUser[i].location.postcode + '<br>' + randomUser[i].location.street,
    }
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(Person));

    // Add fetched persons to profiles array
    function pushToProfiles() {
      profiles.push(Person);
      console.log(profiles);
    }
    pushToProfiles();
  
  console.log(profiles[0]); // RESULTS !!!

});
}
 getTinderProfiles();
console.log(profiles); NO RESULTS !!!
```

Comment: Fetch is asynchronous. The code inside the promise will execute after the fetch finishes; the code after the initial call will (most likely) run before it.

Comment: Also, I saw this question literally after [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898738/why-cant-i-access-a-global-array-in-a-then-scope#52898738) which is the exact same gind of problem.

Comment: Fetch runs asynchronously, so when you are trying to log your results they don't exist yet. `getTinderProfiles().then(profiles => console.log(profiles))` will give you results.

Answer (score -1):

The **getTindersProfile** function you are calling contain an asynchronous function (fetch).

Meaning the system will only make a network call to the *url* but will not wait for any response (asynchronous). So the function will end and continue executing the next function which is the *console.log*.

The system will only execute the function in the *then* (promise) only when the response is ready.

Therefore the *console.log* is executed before the loop that creates and fill the profile array.

To fix your issue, simply create a callback that should be executed only when the response is ready.

```
let url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=11';
let profiles = [];
let Person = new Object();

function getTinderProfiles(callback) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (tinderUsers) {

  // Get 10 users and put data in object
  let randomUser = tinderUsers.results;
  for (let i = 0; i < randomUser.length; i++) {
    Person = {
      picture: randomUser[i].picture.large,
      name: randomUser[i].name.first + ' ' + randomUser[i].name.last,
      age: 'Age: ' + randomUser[i].dob.age,
      location: randomUser[i].location.city + ' ' + randomUser[i].location.postcode + '<br>' + randomUser[i].location.street,
    }
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(Person));

    // Add fetched persons to profiles array
    function pushToProfiles() {
      profiles.push(Person);
      console.log(profiles);
    }
    pushToProfiles();

  console.log(profiles[0]); // RESULTS !!!
  // Call the call back function here
   callback();

});
}
 getTinderProfiles(function(){
     console.log(profiles); // RESULTS AVAILABLE !!!
 });
```

Comment: Mzndako, totally did the trick! Fetch/promises is all kind of new to me but we have to implement them for school projects. This problem is solved, on to the next one :) Thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score -1):

As `getTinderProfiles` is asynchronous you can use a callback function to use it results. You call the callback function when you have processed the results of your `fetch`. The important thing is to declare `profiles` inside `getTinderProfiles`. If you declare it outside of `getTinderProfiles` it will always be empty. Your code is missing a brace closing the `function (tinderUsers)`

```
function getTinderProfiles(useProfiles) {
    let profiles = [];
    fetch(url).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (tinderUsers) {
      // Get 10 users and put data in object
        let randomUser = tinderUsers.results;
        for (let i = 0; i < randomUser.length; i++) {
            Person = {
                picture: randomUser[i].picture.large,
                name: randomUser[i].name.first + ' ' + randomUser[i].name.last,
                age: 'Age: ' + randomUser[i].dob.age,
                location: randomUser[i].location.city + ' ' + randomUser[i].location.postcode + '<br>' + randomUser[i].location.street,
            }
         profiles.push(Person);    
         }
      useProfiles(profiles)
      });
    }


function useProfiles(profiles){
    console.log(profiles);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Steve thanks a lot for the reply! :) Trying it out at the moment but getting a little error in console, saying "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: useProfiles is not a function". I implemented your code as supposed to. Is there anything I must be aware of? The fetch/promise things are new to me but must implement them in schoolproject. Thanks in advance!